# Moving a photo uploaded with Dropzone.js and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, file, upload, dropzone.js

I'm trying to use [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to add an easy drag-and-drop interface for a user to upload up to 10 photos to my server (currently WAMP). I'm using PHP 5.4 on the back end.

Following [this tutorial](http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-file-upload-form-using-dropzonejs-and-php) I got the system working enough to upload acceptable file types to an 'Uploads' folder in my root directory, but I'm stuck on how to make the photos instead upload to a unique directory for each user.

By the time the user gets to my photo upload page, they've already created a folder on my server with a unique name, the path to which has been stored in $_SESSION['requestedDirectory'].

Here is the code used to display the Dropzone form:

```
<form action="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>photo_uploads.php" class="dropzone" id="photoUploadDropzone"></form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.options.photoUploadDropzone = {
      paramName: "file",
      maxFilesize: 5, // MB
      maxFiles: 10,
      addRemoveLinks: true,
      acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/gif",
      accept: function(file, done) {
        done();
      }
    };
</script>
```

As you can see, it sends the data to a file called photo_uploads.php, which has the following code:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
  $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $targetPath = $_SESSION['requestedDirectory']; <--HERE'S THE PROBLEM LINE
  $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];
  move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}
```

As mentioned in the comment above, this file doesn't seem to be able to take data out of a session variable, but I'm not sure why. If I change that line to give the full directory (eg $targetPath = 'C://wamp/www/shops/foldername';) it works fine, but then of course I can't change that foldername dynamically based on which user is using the form.

So to clarify, I'd like to know how to upload the file to the path stored in Session?

## UPDATE: Solved.

For anyone else with the same problem in future, this is what I changed the form to:

```
<form action="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>photo_uploads.php?folder=<?php echo $_SESSION['photosDir']; ?>" class="dropzone" id="photoUploadDropzone"></form>
```

Like Rizwan suggested, by passing the $_SESSION['photosDir'] value in a GET variable it was accessible after the form posted.

The other change I made was to photo_uploads.php, just to the following line:

```
$targetPath = $_GET['folder'];
```

Absolutely no idea why the value wasn't available directly from Session in the first place - I've never heard of Session values going out of scope - but happy to have this problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the requestedDirectory as a query string with the form's action attribute. In that way it can be accessible.