# PHP+Dropzone Uploading in Wrong Directory

Tags: javascript, php, variables, uploading

I have a problem with uploading files with dropzone.js. Here is my code:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $uploads = 'uploads';
    $folder_name = 'hello';
    $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1 //2

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; //3             
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds . $uploads . $ds . $folder_name . $ds; //4
    $targetFile = $targetPath . $_FILES['file']['name']; //5

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6
}

?>
```

And when I upload the image, it only goes to `/uploads/`, but not to `/uploads/$folder_name`.

Even if I write it into `$targetPath` not as variable, like `'hello'` and not as `$folder_name`, it works all right.  And if I echo my `$targetFile`, the directory is all right too.

Comment: Can you echo and post output right before the move_uploaded_file? e.g. $targetPath, $targetFile.  Can you describe permissions in /uploads/hello?  Also move_uploaded_file will return T/F. echo result?
Also, I think you were answering this, but what happens if put a literal string in place of $targetFile in move_uploaded_file().

Comment: @Mark Yes, I can echo everything before move_uploaded_file. Even if permissions are set to 777, it does not work. It all works fine, until I put in the $targetPath another variable than $uploads. If it is like "$uploads . $ds . 'hello'" it works, but even if the variable is 'hello', it does not.

Comment: Sorry, I was actually asking if you could post what it shows when you echo before move_uploaded_file.  
I'd play with uploads being something other than uploads/hello.  Like other/dir and $uploads='uploads/dir' or $uploads='some/other/dir'.  echo it all out.  It sounds even like there's two copies of it.  One that runs and one that you're editing.

Answer (score 0):

only just saw you'd asked me for help based on [my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145371/moving-a-photo-uploaded-with-dropzone-js-and-php) sorry, you've probably moved on by now but here's what I know.

I ended up taking DropZone out of my site during development due to other problems with it, it turns out HTML5 can be used to do everything I needed. In reference to your problem, I found I was unable to move a file using this method to any subfolder of an 'Uploads' directory.

So perhaps try moving the file instead to a completely different directory to see if it works. Also check if you maybe need to include a full path to the file starting with something like 'C://...'